# Basic automation/looping in R

Tags: r

I have a list of many string values (city codes) inside an R vector:
"BOS", "NYC", "AUS", "DAL", LAX", ....

I would like to feed these individually into a function F(city,date) which returns a data frame, and store the results individually like so:

```
bos <- F("BOS", "2016-01-01")  
nyc <- F("NYC", "2016-01-01")  
aus <- F("AUS", "2016-01-01")
```

and so on. How can I achieve this for a list of many cities without going one by one? I apologize for the basic question, and appreciate your help

Comment: `out <- lapply(stringvector, F)` and then you will get a `list` result back that can be subsetted like `out[["BOS"]]` for the individual results.

Comment: did not work unfortunately. unsure if it's because of the custom library function or not

Comment: @Yoav24  Could you please show the custom function

Comment: Well, you changed the function on me! `lapply(stringvector, F, date="2016-01-01")` after the update.

Comment: @akrun the function is GetSummarizedWeather from here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/weatherData/weatherData.pdf

Comment: @thelatemail i did change the function on you :) ... your updated comment helped me solve this. Will be happy to mark your answer as the solution if you reply to the thread

Comment: @Yoav24  I guess the date is `start_date` ?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` to apply the `getSummariseWeather` on a vector of strings ('vec1') and the corresponding 'dates' which go as `start_date` argument for the function.  Here, we are assuming that the `start_date` can change.  If it is not changing then as the @thelatemail suggested approach would be enough

```
Map(getSummarizedWeather, vec1, start_date = dates)
```

---

As a reproducible example

```
library(weatherData)
Map(getSummarizedWeather, c("CDG", "LHR"), start_date = c("2013-09-30",
       "2012-12-12"), end_date = c("2013-10-01", "2012-12-13"))
#$CDG
#         Date Max_TemperatureC Mean_TemperatureC Min_TemperatureC
#1 2013-09-30               18                16               13
#2 2013-10-01               19                16               13

#$LHR
#        Date Max_TemperatureC Mean_TemperatureC Min_TemperatureC
#1 2012-12-12                0                -2               -4
#2 2012-12-13                1                -1               -3
```